# Create matrix grid using TrackBar and TextBoxes

Tags: c#, matrix, dynamic, textbox, flowlayout

I want to create a matrix using trakbar. Horizontal creates new column when increasing and vice verse. Similarily when vertical increase it increases row and when scroll value decreases it must decrease row.

I am using flowlayout.

```
 private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (TextBox tb in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList())
        {
            tb.Dispose();
            flowLayoutPanel1.Width -= 100;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < trackBar1.Value; i++)
        {

            TextBox _text = new TextBox();
            _text.Name = "txt"+i;
            _text.Height = 20;
            _text.Width = 100;
            _text.Text = _text.Name;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(_text);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Width += 100;

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Text = "txt01", Width = 80, Height = 30 });

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Text = "txt01", Width = 80, Height = 30 });
            flowLayoutPanel1.Width += 100;

        }



    }

    int scrollValue = 0;

    private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (scrollValue < trackBar2.Value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < trackBar1.Value; i++)
            {

                TextBox _text = new TextBox();
                _text.Name = "txt" + i;
                _text.Height = 20;
                _text.Width = 100;
                _text.Text = _text.Name;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(_text);
            }

            scrollValue = trackBar2.Value;
        }
        else
            flowLayoutPanel1.Height -= 30;
    }
```

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW6iu.png)

Comment: _facing an issue to achieve._ Is not a useful problem description!

Comment: kindly see 
http://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/matrix/calc/
instead of using combobox , i want to use track bar.

Comment: I read that. But what happens? Do you think we want to guess or try it ourselves? A concise problem description is what you should supply, not just what you want..

Comment: Problem is with logic in using flowlayout or should i try tablelayout . I tried both but does not full fill. so i asked. Would you like to please.
If you can...
would be a great pleasure for me.

Comment: Hint: Do create one function `SetUpGrid(int columns, int rows)` and call it from the two trackbar scroll events. This way you can easily switch to any value picke like the dropdownlist or a numericupdown without changing the core code of setting up the grid..Maybe add an `ìnt width` parameter.. - What is the button supposed to do?

Comment: would you like to code. Harder for me. I am a just beginner

Comment: No, this is not a code writing service. You go ahead and come to ask about specific problems. If you follow my advice you will see that it will be a lot easier and shorter than what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yeah i did it .Bundle of thanks Respected @TaW